# How to create merged shapes based upon blurred originals

Tags: javascript, game-physics, easeljs

I'm using easeljs and attempting to generate a simple water simulation based on this [physics liquid](http://www.patrickmatte.com/stuff/physicsLiquid/) demo.  The issue I'm struggling with is the final step where the author states they "get hard edges".  It is this step that merges the particles into an amorphous blob that gives the effect of cohesion and flow.

In case the link is no longer available, in summary, I've followed the simulation "steps" and created a prototype for particle liquid with the following :

1. Created a particle physics simulation
2. Added a blur filter
3. Apply a threshold to get "hard edges"

So I wrote some code that is using a threshold check to color red (0xFF0000) any shapes/particles that meet the criteria.  In this case the criteria is any that have a color greater than RGB (0,0,200).  If not, they are colored blue (0x0000FF).

```
    var blurFilter = new createjs.BlurFilter(emitter.size, emitter.size*3, 1);
    var thresholdFilter = new createjs.ThresholdFilter(0, 0, 200, 0xFF0000, 0x0000FF);
```

Note that only blue and red appear because of the previously mentioned threshold filter.  For reference, the colors generated are RGB (0,0,0-255).  The method r() simply generates a random number up to the passed in value.

```
    graphics.beginFill(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0,0,r(255)));
```

I'm using this idea of applying a threshold criteria so that I can later set some boundaries around the particle adhesion.  My thought is that larger shapes would have greater "gravity".
You can see from the fountain of particles running below in the attached animated gif that I've completed Steps #1-2 above, but it is this Step #3 that I'm not certain how to apply.  I haven't been able to identify a single filter that I could apply from easeljs that would transform the shapes or merge them in any way.

[image: Particle Fountain]

I was considering that I might be able to do a getBounds() and draw a new shape but they wouldn't truly be merged at that time.  Nor would they exhibit the properties of liquid despite being larger and appearing to be combined.

```
    bounds = blurFilter.getBounds();  // emitter.size+bounds.x, etc.
```

The issue really becomes how to define the shapes that are blurred in the image.  Apart from squinting my eyes and using my imagination I haven't been able to come to a solution.

I also looked around for a solution to apply gravity between shapes so they could, perhaps, draw together and combine but maybe it's simply that easeljs is not the right tool for this.

Thanks for any thoughts on how I might approach this.